# Easy way to get a snapshot from any video under windows with c++?

Tags: c++, video

I am developer a native win32 c++ project which need to take snapshot from video to represent the video.

Tried to take a snapshot with windows media foundation, but supported file formats of this framework is very limited and it do not support Windows XP, is there any easy way to get a snapshot from any video under Windows with pure C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. DirectShow CLSID_SampleGrabber, drawback only supported very limited container/codec.

refer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1353/Extracting-bitmaps-from-movies-using-DirectShow

1. FFmpeg sample grabber, use ffmpeg.exe to generate the preview:
   `ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 out.png`
   Drawback: need to distrubte various files with your application, but supported large collection of codecs/containers.

refer: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video